# If a concave lense is covered half with a piece of paper and is used to look at an object, is the object completely visible?

Tags: optics, lenses

If a **concave** lense is covered half with a piece of a paper and used to look at an object, is the object completely visible or is some part of the object not visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Crude image of concave lens]

Rather crude image of what happens with concave lenses but the image that is formed by the lens will be smaller than the object and formed between the object and the lens. Therefore, the image will always be smaller, and thus, if the lens is covered, the image will not be visible.

On the opposite end of the spectrum, if the lens were convex, the image could be larger than the object, formed behind the lens, and therefore, if a part of the lens were covered, it should be possible to see the image if it is partially covered.